# Android - Vibrate without displaying new Activity?

Tags: java, android, background, alarm, vibration

I have the following code in an android app.  What it currently does is, at the specified time passed with the Calendar when variable, it opens up the RunningActivity (which is blank), vibrates, and sends a notification.  Even if I've pressed the home button and it's running in the background, it starts a new blank RunningActivity and vibrates and sends a notification.  I'm trying to figure out how to do all the stuff in the RunningActivity (Vibrate and send a notification) without opening up the blank RunningActivity, allowing the application to stay in the background.

**I do NOT need help with actually calling the notification or vibration.  I just need to know how to run the actions in the RunningActivity onCreate at a specific time witout opening/showing the RunningActivity.  As seen below, I setup a PendingIntent with an AlarmManagager, the issue is that it is launching an Activity and showing it when all I want it to do is vibrate/send a notification.**

```
public void startAlarm(Activity activity, Calendar when){       
    currentTimerHour = when.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    currentTimerMin = when.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, RunningActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity, 12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)activity.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

RunningActivity Class:

```
public class RunningActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.vibrate(500);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Comment: Why not just send a vibrating notification?

Comment: I already have the vibrating and notification I just don't know how to make it vibrate/send a notification from the background without opening up a new activity. I want it to stay in the background.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with sending a notification from the background? We all do it, all the time?

Comment: The way that I'm doing it above opens up a new blank RunningActivity, I don't know the correct way to set a notification to go off at a specified time without opening up a new Activity.

Comment: Right, so don't do it that way. Create a broadcast intent for alarmmanager, and have the broadcast receiver set your notification. This is a very basic android pattern.

Answer (score 0):

To send Notification From Background:

```
public void createNotification(Context context) {

        // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
        // notification is selected
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,Myexample.class);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);



        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle("My Title")
        .setContentText("My message.")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)

        .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        NotificationManager notificationManager = 
        (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Hide the notification after its selected
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

}
```

Comment: But how do I call this in the background at a specific time?  
  
I'm currently using  
  
    `Intent intent = new Intent(activity, RunningActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity, 12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)activity.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);`  
  
to create an activity at a specific time.  All I need to know is how to run the events in the activity without launching/showing the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use service. Add your vibrator class on Service and call it when you need need it. You can also create a method on your class and call it when you need it.

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(500);
```